# Can I put two switches into Radio Button?

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button

it's possible to put two Switch widgets into one Radio Button?

I tried to find answer for this but I found nothing.

I am not sure what is better option:

- handle Switch widget by myself in code

or if possible

- handle it using Radio Button

EDIT:

This is how it looks in my code.
What I want is when one switch is true, second is false, when first is false, second is true.

```
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.width * 0.03),
                                      child: Switch(
                                        value: locationAllowed,
                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(context, listen: false).loadPosition();
                                            locationAllowed = value;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.width * 0.03),
                                      child: Switch(
                                        value: !locationAllowed,
                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            Provider.of<ControllerProvider>(context, listen: false).notLoadPosition();
                                            locationAllowed = !value;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
```

This is good solution or I should do it different?

Comment: Yes, It can done different ways, like creating two item in another widget  and checking active one

Comment: Can you include your that you;ve tried so far and an image you like to archive

Comment: And an image of the output you are looking for